# is it possible to display additional user info where a user is being linked to in a post?

Tags: apex, chatter, customization

I want to be able to a. add an additional field to the Chatter profile for users to complete, let's call it "Out-of-Office". I then want to be able to display this field in the user selection list when @-mentioning a user in a chatter post. Is it possible to do this? [image]

Comment: If you meant for that image text to be obscured, you should take another pass at it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you asked for is currently not doable through API. For now, if you want the "out of office" message to show up in user selection list, you can update the user name by including "(Out-of-Office thru' 21st Aug'14)". That way, such "out of office" message will also show up in other places that the user name shows up.